# Image stretching in ios not working (ios)

Tags: nativescript

I've got an image and when I apply different stretch modes - aspectFill and aspectFit seem to work as fill mode.

This is ios.

What I'm trying to achieve is to fit a portrait photo w/ proper aspect - even if the device is in landscape mode.

I think aspectFit is the proper mode.

Any help?

Comment: Yes, `aspectFit` should work if you want the entire image to fit into the given container. If you have further issues please share a Playground sample.

Comment: Problem solved - it was a layout issue. thanks.